# Integrate apache http server with tomcat for load balancing

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, apache2

I done a application using EXT JS and deployed in two Apache tomcat instant with same IP and different port number, port number is  8080 and 8081 respectively .i need to do load balancing Apache http server for windows. But i am new to Apache server please help me with it.

Comment: Why not refer the [apache HowTo](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html)

Comment: Also remember that you need to [replicate user sessions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html)